# Hook second router to internet wirelessly?

Tags: router, synology, modem, linksys

I have a router hooked up to a modem, and I have another router. What I want to do, is have the router broadcast a completely different network than my other router, but still have my second router have internet. Is there a way to do this (an Ethernet connection to the modem for the second router is currently not an option for me, due to inaccessibility)? Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I'm currently thinking it might be possible to stream internet from router01 to router02, but not quite sure how to do this

Router brands:

Linksys & Synology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you need is called WDS. Its implementation is, however, specific to each vendor, so having two different brands won't help.

If WDS fails, try your luck with setting up two wireless modes at the same time, namely Client and AP. The radio will switch between them rapidly acting like two machines.

A sure-fire way is having two cheap routers at one spot connected with a short piece of cable. One would be the client and the other the AP. But this adds cost.

No matter the final solution, count on the fact that this will make the internet work slower than it could with a wired network. Especially if the setup uses the same channel for both upstream and downstream, as is likely with repeaters. If you go the two routers way, I advise that the "uplink," or what goes between the main wired router and your intermediate "client" router, is 5GHz. That will help tremendously against losing speed.